# Are there any coding standards for Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, coding-style

I have been searching around for some best practices and was wondering if Dojo has framework specific best practices or is it best to just use generic Javascript standards?

In particular I am mainly looking for some guidelines to function and class commenting if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, this is the project's style guide: [Dojo Style Guide](http://docs.dojocampus.org/developer/styleguide)

Answer (score 2):

One thing I STRONGLY suggest is to NOT pollute your html with dojotype="..." and such invalid attributes and instead add all functionality via script and classnames

Comment: consider also using data-* support in the upcoming 1.6 release: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11829

Answer (score 0):

Best way to start with dojo project...

[Sitepen](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/05/04/what-is-the-best-way-to-start-a-dojo-project/) and [dojo toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/)

hope it will help you...